# Can I see a graph or event log of how my Azure function scales out?

Tags: azure, function, azure-application-insights, autoscaling

I have a Azure function running a python FastApi application. It is set to auto-scale and I would be interested in if and when it actually creates another instance of it.

Application Insights is activated and data is received via the OpenCensus-python integration there, but in "Metric" when I e.g. add "Requests" or "Connections" to the graph it all shows as 0 for the last 48h, while I have requests any minute.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query in Application Insigths:

```
search *
| summarize dcount(cloud_RoleInstance) by cloud_RoleName, bin(timestamp, 1h)
| render columnchart
```

It will show the number of instances per hour.